# How to "validate" a NSTimer after invalidating it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer, nsrunloop

So basically, I have this timer that should be repeated when it receives a key event, and invalidates when the user releases the key.  However, I am unable to "validate" the timer back even by calling the `addTimer:forMode:` in NSRunLoop.  Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You cannot use invalidated timer.

From Apple Docs:

> Once scheduled on a run loop, the timer fires at the specified
>   interval until it is invalidated. A non-repeating timer invalidates
>   itself immediately after it fires. However, for a repeating timer, you
>   must invalidate the timer object yourself by calling its invalidate
>   method. Calling this method requests the removal of the timer from the
>   current run loop; as a result, you should always call the invalidate
>   method from the same thread on which the timer was installed.
>   Invalidating the timer immediately disables it so that it no longer
>   affects the run loop. The run loop then removes and releases the
>   timer, either just before the invalidate method returns or at some
>   later point. Once invalidated, timer objects cannot be reused.

Comment: Interestingly there is NSRunLoop addTimer but there is no removeTimer which could have been useful stopping timer from firing without invalidating it. It must be that creation of timer is cheaper than creation of ports so that apple did not bother adding that api.

Answer (score 14):

Once you've invalidated an NSTimer, you shouldn't use it again.

Instead, create a new timer instance, and use that instance to add to the NSRunLoop's addTimer method.  Personally I prefer just calling NSTimer's scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval because it does everything in one shot.

From NSTimer [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTimer):

> Calling this method requests the removal of the timer from the current
>   run loop; as a result, you should always call the invalidate method
>   from the same thread on which the timer was installed. Invalidating
>   the timer immediately disables it so that it no longer affects the run
>   loop. The run loop then removes and releases the timer, either just
>   before the invalidate method returns or at some later point. Once
>   invalidated, timer objects cannot be reused.